# progressive omissions in sentences

Tags: grammar

> It happened, because these bad people were evil and these evil people
> were stupid, (and) these evil people (were) irresponsible (and) evil
> people (were) really ignorant.

> It happened, because these bad people were evil and these evil people
> were stupid, these evil people irresponsible evil
> people really ignorant.

So is this ok? How is this not ok, and what are the kind of omissions that are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to shorten it by omitting bits, it would be:

> It happened, because these bad people were evil and these evil people were stupid,
> (and these evil people were) irresponsible and (these evil people were) really ignorant.

> It happened, because these bad people were evil and these evil people were stupid, irresponsible and really ignorant.

(Note that in a list of several things only the last one needs an "and" before it, though you can put "and" on the others if you want to, that's also correct.)

Although, if this sentence is meant to be comical (it reads comically to me, anyway), I'd say you'd get better comic effect by continuing the progression and saying:

> It happened, because these bad people were evil and these evil people were stupid, and these stupid people were irresponsible and these irresponsible people were really ignorant.